# Custom antd Input component -> User will enter the hours and minutes, the data must be stored in minutes (integer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd, data-conversion

I have been trying to Implement this custom antd input, but the conversions are always tricky. Any feedback is appreciated :)

Rules:

1. User will enter HH:MM
2. the value of the form item (currentValue) must be in Minutes (stored as integer in backend)
   Any suggestion on How to make this work?

Currently this input is just not taking the values as soon as I enter more than 2 digits I lost the focus of that field somehow.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Col, InputNumber, Row } from 'antd'

function MinutesInput({ value: currentValue, onChange, type = 'daily', ...props }) {
  // if type is daily, set the limit of hours to 24
  // if type is weekly, set the limit of hours to 168
  // the user enter the value in HH:MM
  // the value is stored in minutes
  // the value is displayed in HH:MM

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col span={24}>
        <InputNumber
          className="w-100"
          min={type === 'daily' ? 0 : 0}
          max={type === 'daily' ? 24 : 168}
          formatter={(value) => {
            if (value) {
              const hours = Math.floor(value / 60)
              const minutes = value % 60
              return `${hours}:${minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes}`
            } else {
              return ''
            }
          }}
          parser={(value) => {
            // if (value) {
            //   const [hours, minutes] = value.split(':')
            //   return parseInt(hours) * 60 + parseInt(minutes)
            // } else {
            //   return 0
            // }

            if (type === 'daily') {
              if (value) {
                const [hours, minutes] = value.split(':')
                if (hours > 24) {
                  return 24 * 60 + parseInt(minutes)
                } else {
                  return parseInt(hours) * 60 + parseInt(minutes)
                }
              } else {
                return 0
              }
            } else if (type === 'weekly') {
              if (value) {
                const [hours, minutes] = value.split(':')
                if (hours > 168) {
                  return 168 * 60 + parseInt(minutes)
                } else {
                  return parseInt(hours) * 60 + parseInt(minutes)
                }
              } else {
                return 0
              }
            }
          }}
          value={currentValue || 0}
          addonAfter={currentValue && `${Math.floor(currentValue / 60)}h ${currentValue % 60}m`}
          onChange={onChange}
          {...props}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )
}

export default MinutesInput
```

Usage:

```
import MinutesInput from './MinutesInput'
return <MinutesInput />
```

Comment: Could you explain the daily, weekly concept with an example? I'll modify my answer once you give me an example

Comment: I am testing the answer provided, will give you the feedback soon, thank you very much :)

Comment: Is the solution working? any updates?

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function Input() {
  const [mins, setMins] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (/^\d{2,}:[1-5][0-9]$/.test(event.target.value)) {
      const [hr, min] = event.target.value.split(':');
      setMins(parseInt(hr) * 60 + parseInt(min));
    } else {
      setMins(null);
    }
    
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        pattern={'^([0-1]?d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?d))?$'}
        placeholder={'Enter time in HH:MM format'}
        required
      />
      {mins && <p>Total Minutes = {mins}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the snippet written for your 2 rules..